# vsphere to install on ubuntu desktop

Tags: vmware-vsphere

we have some servers that Vmware workstation installed on them.
there is no problem controlling Vmware via Vsphere in windows.
but since we use Linux , we could not find a graphical UI to work on our servers Vmware.
is there any free application such as vsphere for ubuntu desktop .

comment : linux version installed on our pc is ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop

Comment: We use Web-version, or run vSphere in VirtualBox VM.

Answer (score 1):

The Vsphere client in linux doesn't exist. It's only available on Windows afaik...
There's only the web-gui when using vmware esx.
But if you have VMware Workstation on your linux pcs as well you can also manage VMware ESX.
Look here for further information: https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2013/12/using-vmware-workstation-to-manage-your-esxi-hosts-and-vms-2.html